# Check if a list consists of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to check if all elements of a list are numbers. I've tried

```
t = {5/4, 12}
MatrixQ[t, NumberQ]
MemberQ[t, NumberQ]
And @@ Table[NumberQ[t[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[t]}]
```

but only the last one yields the desired result. Is there a better way to check?

Comment: `VectorQ[t, NumberQ]` or `AllTrue[t, NumberQ]` should do the trick - the [`VectorQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorQ.html) version only accepts lists of numbers, while the [`AllTrue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html) version accepts any head

Comment: Maybe `ContainsOnly[t[[All, 0]], {Rational, Integer}]` possibly with the addition of `Real` and/or `Complex`

Comment: @LukasLang, Thanks, I like your answer the best. Sorry I cannot upvote it!

Comment: `Table[ Im[z] == 0, {z, t} ]`

Comment: I'm confused both by the question asking for `Reals` and `NumberQ` as if they were the same when they are not, and by the fact that Irrationals like $\pi$ and $e$ are not `NumberQ`. You are getting contradictory answers! Can you please [edit] and clarify?

Comment: Also `NumberQ[I]== True`!

Comment: @rhermans. You're right. I expect any number in my lists to be a real number and that was the source of the confusion. I edited the question

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Element`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html):

> Element[{$x_1 , x_2 , \ldots$}, dom]
>   *asserts that all the* $x_i$ *are elements of* dom.

Using mgamer's example list:

```
{Pi, 0.4, 1, 2/2, 1./3} ∈ Reals
```

> True

The built-in mathematical constants:

```
{Catalan, °, E, EulerGamma, Glaisher, GoldenRatio, Khinchin, MachinePrecision, π} ∈ Reals
```

> True

```
{Pi, 1 + I, 1, .5} ∈ Reals
```

> False

Comment: Seeing your solution I recognize, that I misinterpreted the original question. There was no question about Reals... ;-) Sometimes I see, what I want to see ;-)

Comment: @mgamer, the original post _was_ about reals:)

Comment: :-)) Thank you! Reading the hidden comments is sometimes enlightening....

Answer (score 3):

Given a list:

```
list = {Pi, 0.4, 1, 2/2, 1./3}
```

you can do:

```
And @@ (Head[#] === Real & /@ list)
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `MatchQ` and `NumericQ`:

```
t = {5/4, 12, Pi, 0.4};

MatchQ[t, {__?NumericQ}]

(*True*)
```

Another way to do this, nice and shorter (Thanks to @Syed!):

```
AllTrue[NumericQ][t]
```

Comment: `AllTrue[NumericQ][t]`

Comment: Nice and shorter, @Syed! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {EulerGamma, Pi, 0.4, 1, 2/2, 1./3};
```

Since V 13.3 we have `RealValuedNumberQ` and `RealValuedNumericQ`

```
AllTrue[list, RealValuedNumericQ]
```

True

```
AllTrue[list, RealValuedNumberQ]
```

False (* because of `EulerGamma` *)